# Issue with controls on tabControl - no data refreshing before clicking on all tabPages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a problem with controls nested in a TabControl.  I have a TabControl with n TabPages, with a DataGridView on each TabPage.  Each DataGridView has a CheckBoxC column.  I populate all datagridviews with different datasources (so each has different types of data). This is working ok!

---

I have added a ComboBox column so I can select all the rows on all DataGridViews.  I do this programmatically (on a button click), and the counting of the selection is ok, except that the ticks are not added to checkBox cell of DataGridViews except on TabPage #1 (the one that I can see on startup).

---

If I click all the tabPages **before** I go and select all the rows in DataGridViews, the code works fine, and the ticks are added to all the rows (like I wanted).

But why this does not work without clicking all the tabPages?  Is there any bug or something of TabControl?

Comment: This is by design, binding only occurs when a control is visible.  It is an optimization, you'll need to deal with that.

Comment: So I have to bind data for each datagridview when appropriate tabPage is selected? This cannot be true, because the data are binded jsut fine - only ticks (for checkBox cells) are not added - when I set Value property of it to true.

Comment: I think you might find a solution in my answer to [Does data binding work on invisible control?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943473/does-data-binding-work-on-invisible-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this answer is correct for WPF, not positive about WinForms though.  With WPF at least, it's a visually based interface, so the program does not load any of the objects/controls/etc on other tabs until they are clicked on.  So it wouldn't be a bug, it's a part of the design.

I had a similar problem with trying to clear all textboxes on multiple tabs with a single button.  I never did get it working, but I know there should be a way by using a combination of `VisualTreeHelper` and a `foreach` statement.

Again, this is based off of WPF and not WinForms, but hopefully it can point you in the right direction as to how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to add this in the load event of the form.

```
this.tabcontrol1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```